# How to get data in Array category wise?

Tags: php, arrays

I have below data coming from loop:

```
$array = Array(
[0]=>Array(
    [0]=>Cat 1
    [1]=> Q1
    [2]=> A1
    )
[1]=>Array(
    [0]=>Cat 1
    [1]=> Q2
    [2]=> A2
    )
[2]=>Array(
    [0]=>Cat 2
    [1]=> Q1
    [2]=> A1
    )
[3]=>Array(
    [0]=>Cat 3
    [1]=>Sub Cat 3
    [2]=>Q1
    [3]=>A1
    )
[4]=>Array(
    [0]=>Cat 3
    [1]=>Sub Cat 3
    [2]=>Q2
    [3]=>A2
    )       
)
)
```

I need data in Array like

```
$array_res = Array(
['Cat 1']=>Array(
    [0]=>Array(
        [0]=> Q1
        [1]=> A1
        )
    [1]=>Array(
        [0]=> Q2
        [1]=> A2
        )
    )
['Cat 2']=>Array(
    [0]=>Array(
        [0]=> Q1
        [1]=> A1
        )
    )
['Cat 3']=>Array(
    ['Sub Cat 3']=>Array(
        [0]=>Array(
            [0]=> Q1
            [1]=> A1
        )
        [1]=>Array(
            [0]=> Q2
            [1]=> A2
        )
        )
    )

)
```

It should return data in Array/Associative Array. So can fetch data loop wise & print it. I want the arrays created dynamically when there are array values inside an array like sub cat 3.

Comment: Is you original array keyed? ie. ```0 => ['name' => 'Cat1', 'question_1' => 'Q1', 'answer_1' => 'A1']```

Comment: In original array all will be in 1. Yes you are correct. `0 => [ 'Cat1', 'Q1', 'A1']`

Comment: Without adding keys to the original array it will be difficult. As an example what if ```0 => ['Cat1', 'A1', 'Q1']``` and ```1 => ['Cat2', 'Q2,' A2']```. In the first array the Question and Answer are swapped. If you create the the first array create it using keys not jus indexes, ie. ```$result[] = ['category' => 'Cat 1', 'answer' => 'A1',  'question' => 'Q1'];```. Now when you work with it is it easier as you know what is a category, what is a question, what is an answer and sub category etc.

Comment: I think it would be better if you modify the loop that produced the data rather than changing the result coming out from that loop

Comment: It's really hard to understand the array organization from your notation. What does `A1 -> 1 -> Q2` mean? Why would an answer point to another question? Could you use something like PHP array literal syntax, JSON, or `var_dump` format?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code. I've explained my answer with my comment. You can try it here https://3v4l.org/K1kZ6

**Answer:**

```
$cat_array = array(
    0=>array(
        0=>'Cat 1',
        1=>'Q1',
        2=>'A1'
        ),
    1=>array(
        0=>'Cat 1',
        1=>'Q2',
        2=>'A2'
        ),
    2=>array(
        0=>'Cat 2',
        1=>'Q1',
        2=>'A1'
        ),
    3=>array(
        0=>'Cat 3',
        1=>'Sub Cat 3',
        2=>'Q1',
        3=>'A1'
        ),
    4=>array(
        0=>'Cat 3',
        1=>'Sub Cat 3',
        2=>'Q2',
        3=>'A2'
        )       
);

$converted_array = array();
foreach($cat_array as $key => $array){

    // Split the cat and 3
    $temp = explode(' ', $array[0]);

    //Check if key(Cat 1,2,3,etc..) exists in converted array
    if(!array_key_exists($array[0],$converted_array)){
        $converted_array[$array[0]] = array();
    }

    //Get and check if there is a Sub Cat
    $sub_temp = explode(' ', $array[1]);

    //Check in array if there is a sub in $sub_temp array. 
    if(!in_array('sub' , array_map("strtolower", $sub_temp))){
        //If doesn't have sub
        //Store key(Cat 1,2,3...) before we unset 
        $temp_key = $array[0];
        unset($array[0]);

        //Get the total count to provide as our starting index
        $l = count($converted_array[$temp_key]);

        // $temp_key = "Cat 1,2,3,etc..." and $l = 0,1,2...
        foreach($array as $val){
            $converted_array[$temp_key][$l][]= $val;
        }
    }else{

        //Check if sub is inside of sub array
        if(!array_key_exists($array[1],$converted_array[$array[0]])){
            $converted_array[$array[0]][$array[1]] = array();
        }

        //Same as the above, we store key first before we unset.
        $temp_key = $array[0];
        $temp_sub_key = $array[1];

        unset($array[0]);
        unset($array[1]);
        //Same as the above but with sub category
        $l = count($converted_array[$temp_key][$temp_sub_key]);
        foreach($array as $val){
            $converted_array[$temp_key][$temp_sub_key][$l][]= $val;
        }   
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($converted_array);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [Cat 1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Q1
                    [1] => A1
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Q2
                    [1] => A2
                )

        )

    [Cat 2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Q1
                    [1] => A1
                )

        )

    [Cat 3] => Array
        (
            [Sub Cat 3] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Q1
                            [1] => A1
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Q2
                            [1] => A2
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing much to explain.. Have taken care of sub category as well.

```
    <?php

        $array = Array(
        Array(
            "Cat 1",
            "Q1",
            "A1"
            ),
        Array(
            "Cat 1",
            "Q2",
            "A2"
            ),
        Array(
            "Cat 2",
            "Q1",
            "A1"
            ),
        Array(
            "Cat 3",
            "Sub Cat 3",
            "Q1",
            "A1"
            ),
        Array(
            "Cat 3",
            "Sub Cat 3",
            "Q2",
            "A2"
            ),
            Array(
                "Cat 2",
                "Q2",
                "A2"
            )
        );

        $array_res = array();

        foreach($array as $key=> $val) {
            if(is_array($val)) {
                $catName = $val[0];
                //echo "category = $catName <br>";                    
                //echo count($val) . "<br>";
                if(count($val) === 3) {
                    // no sub category
                    $this_arr = array();
                    foreach($val as $key1 => $val1) {
                        if($key1 !=0) {
                           //echo "$key1 => $val1 <br>";  
                            $this_arr[] = $val1;
                        }                        
                    }

                    $array_res[$catName][] = $this_arr; 
                }
                else {
                    // there is subcategory as well
                    $subCatName = $val[1];
                    $this_arr = array();
                    foreach($val as $key1 => $val1) {
                        if($key1 !=0 && $key1 !=1 ) {
                            //echo "$key1 => $val1 <br>";  
                            $this_arr[] = $val1;
                        }                        
                    }

                    $array_res[$catName][$subCatName][] = $this_arr;                         
                }                 

            }
            else {
               // echo "$key => $val <br/>";
            }


        }


        echo "<br/>Result Array <br>";
        foreach($array_res as $key => $val) {
            if(is_array($val)) {
                echo "$key<br>";
                foreach($val as $key1 => $val1) {
                    echo "$key1 <br>";
                    if(is_array($val1)) {
                        foreach($val1 as $key2 => $val2) {
                            if(is_array($val2)) {
                                //echo "$key2 <br>";
                                foreach($val2 as $key3 => $val3) {
                                    echo "$key3 => $val3 <br>";
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                echo "$key2 => $val2 <br>";    
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                echo "$key => $val <br/>";    
            }

        }

    ?>
```